# Install Ubuntu to second hard drive without shutting down Windows

Tags: system-installation, virtualization

I'm using Windows 10 and I have an extra hard drive. This isn't essential, but is there a way to install Ubuntu onto that hard drive without shutting down the PC?

While we're on that train: after Ubuntu's installed on the hard disk, is it possible to run it in a virtual machine from Windows as well as boot my PC into it?

Thanks for any offerings to my chronic curiosity

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible. I use this method for Windows host on HDD and Ubuntu guest on SSD.

All you need is to attach physical disk to the virtual machine with [`createrawvmdk` internal command](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/UserManual.html#adv-storage-config).

You need to determine disk number with `diskmgmt.msc` and then run `cmd` as administrator and execute (**but be careful with last argument** - it is harddrive path, in my example it is `\\.\PHYSICALDRIVE1`):

`"C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\VBoxManage.exe" internalcommands createrawvmdk -filename C:\ubuntu-drive.vmdk -rawdisk \\.\PHYSICALDRIVE1`

Then you need to run VirtualBox as administrator and attach hard disk file `C:\ubuntu-drive.vmdk` to the VM, then install Ubuntu as usual. When it is installed, you can eject ISO and run this VM inside Windows.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using windows 10, the easiest way to go is to use Hyper-V.
Here is a tutorial from microsoft on how to create Ubuntu Vm's
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/hyper-v-on-windows/quick-start/quick-create-virtual-machine
Just use a virtual hard disk (.vhd) in your extra hard drive
enjoy!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure what you mean by install Ubuntu without shutting down the PC. If you mean to install the two operating systems side-by-side then yes, that's no problem. Try Googling **dual boot** Ubuntu.

If you want access to your **actual** Ubuntu installation via a Virtual Machine in Windows, you need to create a pointer. I've done the opposite on Ubuntu where I boot into my Windows while logged in to Ubuntu. There's a good tutorial on it here: [Boot into Windows on Ubuntu](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/use-your-windows-10-instantly-inside-ubuntu-linux-from-pavic/) - I'm sure with SOME Googling you can figure out how to do it from Windows to Ubuntu as well.